# PHP list files from database each record own information

Tags: php, sql, database

I've got database full of files, user wil choose what should be show, for instance: only pictures, text etc... this on files.php through form sent to finder.php

Then files are listed in table like first row file1, second row file2...n row file n - finder.php

And then user can click on each of it and gets info about it, on new page called info.php
like rank, comments, etc...

How to do it, when i click on specific row, correct data from database will be loaded?

Comment: Show what you've tried and explain what's not working.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0e5304112afd2a19621f

That html page with form is not here, there is no problem.

Comment: and there is code of the form https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8730a23a52866bc1d9d

Comment: @frky Put your code in the question.

Comment: I think its too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Option
The link is a submit button of a form. So you can send data to info.php with POST method.

```
<form>
 <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="Value">
 <input type="submit" value="Link"> // this is your link
</form>
```

2.Option
You can send some data with the link

```
<a href="info.php?data=data">
```

so you can get those informations with GET method.

**Update:**

instead of this line

```
echo "<td><a href="."info.php".">Zde</a></td>";
```

put this

```
echo '<td><a href="info.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Zde</a></td>';
```

and in the info.php you can get that id with this line:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: But first its sent to finder.php based on variables are listed files from database and then i want to click on some of it and gets information.

Comment: actually i don't understand what you really want to do.
You are at the finder.php where you list those items.
And when you click one of those you are going to the info.php where you show some information about that file only.
Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I have to show some info about it, those informations are saved in database. So if i click on first file/row it will show info about file with id = 1.

Comment: So you can add at the sql code that.
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$id."' "

Comment: Yes, its working, thank you man! And i dont need that form you posted. Just update that echo line and get id in info.php :)